# Component styles not applying in emulated view encapsulation (Angular 5)

Tags: angular

I'm using PrimeNG library (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng) in an Angular 5 app and I've realized that, if I use some of its controls inside an Angular component with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` I can't apply to them any custom style to them.

For example, I'm using the `p-checkbox` control inside a component, and I have the following (horrible) CSS rules in its style file:

```
th {
  background-color: olive !important;
}

.ui-chkbox {
  background-color: aqua !important;
  height: 2.5rem !important;
}
```

NOTE: `ui-chkbox` is the DIV containing the checkbox.

Here's how it looks if I set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`:

[image]

If I change to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`, it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the component `th` tag is still being styled but the checkbox component is not. I thought that the emulated view encapsulation was intended to "isolate" the component styles so they don't collide with others defined outside, but it seems that it also affects to inner components.

Could somebody explain this behaviour? I've read a couple of encapsulation tutorials but I couldn't find the reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot change the primeng component styles without using the `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component.
>
> They are **not inherited by any components nested within the template** nor by any content projected into the component.

You can only target the host element of each child component. You will not be able to target any internal elements used inside the component.

[Style scope](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope)

Comment: Your answer has helped me understand view encapsulation better. Also, reading PrimeNG documentation, I've realized that you can apply an `styleClass` directive to the component to help you customize it without overriding global styles. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** need to, you can still use the *deprecated* `::ng-deep` to target any child component:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-chkbox {
  background-color: aqua !important;
  height: 2.5rem !important;
}
```

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's
>   own template.
>
> Use the /deep/ shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style
>   down through the child component tree into all the child component
>   views. The /deep/ combinator works to any depth of nested components,
>   and it applies to both the view children and content children of the
>   component.

See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep for more.

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). **Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred** for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, as well as Tomasz, I try to avoid using deprecated solutions. To customize the PrimeNG checkbox control only inside the component I want, I'll use its `styleClass` directive, which allows to apply an extra class to be more specific in the CSS file. For example: `<p-checkbox styleClass="customCheckbox">` allows me to define custom styles with `.customCheckbox.ui-chkbox` selector.

Comment: ::ng-deep is still the Angular team preferred way to achieve if you **really** have a use case for that.

Comment: but looks like you don't since you have some alternatives in the library you use!

Comment: this is the actual solution. Great work. many thanks